# Asana - Query for tasks using multiple tags

Tags: api, asana

I need to use the Asana API to query for all tasks that has given set of tags. For example tasks that has all 3 of these tags: `Development`, `IT`, `Sprint-1`

I'v read through the docs and only found that you can query with one tag. Please help. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a great way to directly query for tasks that have multiple specific tags.

A possible workaround would be to query for tasks with one of the tags, say `Development`, and then filter the result set by only taking tasks that also have both the `IT` and `Sprint-1` tags.

You can get tag information in the result set using the `opt_fields` parameter, i.e.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <my_personal_access_token>" "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags/<tag_id>/tasks?opt_fields=name,tags,tags.name"`